# Is it possible to re-run configure without specifying --prefix, but yet keeping the prefix specified on an earlier run?

Tags: caching, configure, autotools, prefix, autoconf

Suppose I am creating Makefiles for some project using autotools, and I am frequently changing the `configure.ac` file. After that, I have to update the build files:

```sh
/path/to/project/dir$ autoreconf -vfi
...
/path/to/project/dir$ ./configure --prefix=/home/user/.local
...
/path/to/project/dir$
```

Can I avoid specifying the `--prefix` argument each time I ran `autoreconf` ? If I simply omit it the next time I run `./configure`, the installation prefix is reset to `/usr/local`, but I want it to keep the value `/home/user/.local` I speciified on the first run of `./configure`.

**Note:** Of course, I could create an alias in my `.bashrc` file:

```sh
alias configure="./configure --prefix=/home/user/.local
```

but, that way, I would have to edit the `.bashrc` file every time I want to change the prefix path of the project.

**Note 2:** I observed that skipping re-running `./configure` makes `make` run some `config.status` script, so this should be possible !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am frequently changing the `configure.ac` file. After that, I have to update the build files

Well no, not necessarily.  At least, not manually.  If you have already configured the project at least once, and you still have the generated Makefile and other configuration results, then each time you `make`, the build system will automatically rebuild itself and reconfigure the project if needed.

> I observed that skipping re-running `./configure` makes `make` run some `config.status` script, so this should be possible !

Indeed, `config.status` is written by `configure`.  It memorializes the `configure` arguments and the results of its tests, and it is the component that actually builds output files such as makefiles.  It includes support for re-running `configure` with the same arguments as were used for the previous `configure` run (when `config.status` itself was built).

If you're satisfied to use all the same `configure` arguments (including precious environment variables) when you reconfigure after making changes then the easiest thing to do is just let `make` handle it.  This will cover you in many cases.  However, if you have removed your `Makefile`, or, especially, your `config.status`, then the needed information is no longer available.  In addition to removing those files manually, you will also remove them if you `make distclean` or `make maintainer-clean`.

Of course, this does not help if you need to add, remove, or modify any `configure` arguments, nor if you otherwise run `configure` directly.  if you want to cover such cases then I see no alternative to an approach along the general lines of the alias alternative you suggested.  I would include  in that class options such as creating a wrapper or environment configuration script in the project, or using the `alias` command manually to add an alias that is scoped to the current shell execution context only.

Comment: Yeah, I already observed that if I run only `make` after modifying `configure.ac` or `Makefile.am` `config.status` is run. But I never saw `autoreconf` being run - is that ever run if I don't run it by hand ?

Comment: @Programmer, `autoreconf` probably is not run.  Instead, `autoconf`, `automake`, `autoheader`, or other specific autotools will be run as appropriate for the specific build system components that are out of date.